# How to upgrade HDD to SSD and replace the optical drive with HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware-recommendation, optical-drive

I am trying to understand the process of switching out my HDD for an SSD and then replacing my optical drive with the same HDD just removed in a late 2011 Macbook Pro 15.4".

Is there any benefit to doing this vs. just replacing the optical drive with a new SSD and leaving the HDD where it is at?

My main intent in adding a SSD is to increase the speed of my computer and not necessarily adding more space. My HDD is 750GB and I'm not even close to filing it up. I do have programs on my HDD like Microsoft Office that I don't want to lose and don't have the means of reinstalling.

Any suggestions would be great and a detailed description of how to go about this would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look - we have quite a few questions covering this - you may want to edit your question to differentiate it from similar questions.

- [Replacing SuperDrive with secondary storage?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/replacing-superdrive-with-secondary-storage)
- [What are some tips for replacing my MacBook Pro hard disk with SSD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/what-are-some-tips-for-replacing-my-macbook-pro-hard-disk-with-ssd)
- [Recommended MacBook Pro 13 (mid 2012) SSD upgrade?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54561/recommended-macbook-pro-13-mid-2012-ssd-upgrade)
- [Compatible SSD for Macbook Pro (replace HDD)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30554/compatible-ssd-for-macbook-pro-replace-hdd)
- [Will a standard MacBook Pro optical-bay HDD caddy fit a non-unibody MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22840/will-a-standard-macbook-pro-optical-bay-hdd-caddy-fit-a-non-unibody-macbook-pro)
- [Is it worth upgrading my MacBook hard drive to an SSD?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16287/is-it-worth-upgrading-my-macbook-hard-drive-to-an-ssd)
- [How to install an Operating System after replacing optical Drive by a second HDD on MacBook white late 2009?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68475/how-to-install-an-operating-system-after-replacing-optical-drive-by-a-second-hdd)
- [Are "generic" Optical Bay Hard Drive Enclosures for Macbook Pros just as good as Optibay/OWC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55671/are-generic-optical-bay-hard-drive-enclosures-for-macbook-pros-just-as-good-as)

Comment: I'd also suggest looking at [this Reddit /r/Apple page](http://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/165vde/has_anyone_seen_any_updated_information_about/) for some feedback about SSDs in general, although it is more specifically about "fusion" drives.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used these [OWC optical drive replacement kits](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/drive_bracket/datadoubler/) but haven't ever heard anything negative about them; the power draw from the SSD is so much less than a traditional spinning HDD that I doubt you'll notice much difference in battery life.

Swapping the HDD out is trivial; replacing the optical with any other drive will be a bit more complicated, but do-able.

If you decide to only upgrade the HDD to SSD and retain your optical drive, you could use any external 2.5" SATA to USB enclosure to [clone](http://www.bombich.com/) from the HDD to the SSD; I've done this plenty of times.

In any case, upgrading to a SSD is a really great performance improvement, especially on an older portable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You mentioned that I can use a SATA to USB enclosure to clone the HDD to SSD, does that include programs. In other words would I be able to transfer my microsoft office program (not just files) from my HDD to SSD without reinstalling?

Comment: Yes; in this context 'cloning' means copying the entire drive - OS/system, applications, data - from one volume to another.  The utility I linked to, [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/), is the standard for Macs for cloning systems (even while booted).  If you used that, your new SSD would have the exact same OS, apps, and data (just be tremendously faster).