# Would Apple (UK) change a part with another for you?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, optical-drive, warranty

I was just wondering if Apple would swap my Optical Drive on my MacBook Pro for an SSD, and how much it would cost, as I would rather they do it and I keep my warranty then doing it myself and losing my warranty. I have AppleCare if that makes a difference, and the laptop is also still in it's 1st year warranty.
I would be supplying the SSD and bracket and cable and anything else needed to fit the SSD into the MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be very surprised if they would - there's no standard Apple product to replace an optical drive with an SSD.

You'd either need to do it yourself using any one of the third-party optical bay solutions (see [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76781/how-to-upgrade-hdd-to-ssd-and-replace-the-optical-drive-with-hdd)) or have a third party hardware repair firm do it for you. In both cases, however, you'd be voiding your Apple warranty as the optical drive is not a user serviceable part.

Comment: what I meant was, if I bought the SSD and bracket and cables, would apple swap the ssd for the optical drive for me? even if I had to pay them, so as not to void my warranty.

Comment: Indeed, I thought that was what you meant, hence my comment in the first line of my reply. No harm in asking Apple, but I'm guessing they won't do the swap as you'd be making use of third-party hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst an Apple Retail Store may not do this for you, i'm pretty sure an Apple Certified Technician would do this for you.

Use this [locator](https://locate.apple.com/uk/en/), click on service and enter your post code for a list in your area.

Comment: I'm going to get my MacBook checked anyways, so I'll ask them then.

Comment: @D.Shah Ok fine, i'm pretty sure that an Apple Certified Technician will help you, if the Apple Store won't. Good luck.